# How to get rid of this memory leak

Tags: swift, xcode, automatic-ref-counting

Now I'm working with Leaks tool in Xcode and there is one leak in the last line of this chunk of code:

```
let geocoder = CLGeocoder()
    geocoder.geocodeAddressString(location) { (placemarks, error) in

        if let error = error {
            print(error)
            return
        }

        guard let placemarks = placemarks else { return }

        let placemark = placemarks.first

        let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
        annotation.title = self.place.name
        annotation.subtitle = self.place.type

        guard let placemarkLocation = placemark?.location else { return }

        annotation.coordinate = placemarkLocation.coordinate

        self.mapView.showAnnotations([annotation], animated: true)
        self.mapView.selectAnnotation(annotation, animated: true)
    }
```

To prevent this leak I use capture list [weak self] in the closure:

```
geocoder.geocodeAddressString(location) { [weak self] (placemarks, error) in

        guard let self = self else { return }
```

But this doesn't prevent my code from the leak at the same last line of code. But sometimes if I restart my project several times this leak goes away even if I remove this capture list [weak self].
What I do wrong guys can find logic to this behavior.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: How do you check that it actually leaks? 

The best way to check is to implement `deinit` method in your class and put a breakpoint there, if the code execution doesn't stop there when the object is expected to be deallocated – you have an issue with memory management

Answer (score 0):

You are making this `self` reference  as strong capturing it try in this,

```
        guard let self = self else { return }
```

Try to simply use `self?` and check if there is still memory leak issue,
this [article](https://stablekernel.com/how-to-prevent-memory-leaks-in-swift-closures/) is amazing explaining a lot i recommend you take a look at it

Comment: It doesn't affect anything

Comment: Thanks for article